# recursively step through asp table (that has been populated with a query)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

so basically I have a query that populates a table in an asp page like so:

```
<div class="span10">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped with-check" runat="server" id="noncompulsarymodules">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"  Text= '<%# Eval("ModuleId")  %>' style="display:none;" /> </td>
         <td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("noncompcode")  %>' /> </td>
         <td><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("noncomptitle") %>' /> </td>
         <td><asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("moduleunits") %>' /> </td>
         <td class="center" style="overflow:hidden;">  <asp:Label ID="ModuleDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("noncompdesc") %>' /></td>
         <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

basically what I want to do is cycle through the table and take the rows that have been checked and put them into a query.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Google "Repeater in Asp.Net"

Comment: Make the checkboxes part of a form and process whatever gets posted with that form.

Comment: I have tried a "foreach" loop in the code behind file to go through the table and check which text boxes are checked but the loop is unable to access the table at all. perhaps I am not declaring it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at using an ASP.Net Gridview control with a checkbox / templatefield column.

You will then be able to iterate through the GridViewRows and get the checked columns.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help